# Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject.GetVstoObject method is missing excel list object

Tags: excel-addins, listobject

I wanna use Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject.GetVstoObject() but its missing.

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uVvw.png)

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(listObject);
```

Thanks